# Which fonts is Texworks using to replace missing system fonts?

Tags: fonts, pdf, texworks

#### Issue

I am working with a Linux system and my **evince** PDF viewer cannot visualize and print a document in full because it lacks some fonts. According to `pdffonts` these are Helvetica and Helvetica bold --- proprietary fonts, as I understood. If I go to File > Properties > Fonts Tab in evince, that Helvetica has been substituted with TeXGyreHeros-Regular and I also see the path to the otf file in the Texlive 2016 that I installed (thus not a native install).

#### Research

I see the text in full if I open the same document with **Texworks**. Apparently, Texworks has access to those fonts, or suitable replacements thereof. Pity though that Texworks has no printing capabilities and relies on Evince for doing this, whence I'm back to square zero.

#### Questions

How can I makes sure that evince fetches the fonts that Texworks has fetched?

Comment: Strange. In Evince, go to File > Properties, and choose the Fonts tab. Does the PDF have non-embedded fonts? If so, it did not originate with LaTeX.

Comment: Also: The Okular PDF viewer has different properties than Evince. That might or might not help.

Comment: @RobtA Strange indeed. If I go to File > Properties > Fonts Tab in evince, I discover that, for instance, Helvetica has been substituted with TeXGyreHeros-Regular and I also see the path to the otf file in my Texlive installation. In a way you have pointed me towards a near-answer to the second question --- please feel free to convert your comment into a fully-fledged answer. But as a matter of fact evince does not show this font, which is probably a question for another forum.

Comment: Evince should be able to show TeXGyre-Heros (which is supposed to be a Helvetica-like font). Do try Okular (it is probably in your Linux distro software repository). If that doesn't work either, then my only guess is that... actually, I have no clue. Not necessary to make my reply an answer.

Comment: This sounds like a font configuration problem to me. Your font management should be configured so that something always gets substituted. That doesn't work for special symbols or scripts, but it should work fine for basic stuff. That is, even if you didn't have a clone installed, it should substitute something. But this is probably not something Evince does. It is something your font manager does. (And the basic 35 postscript fonts are core and should be provided in some form by any current system reasonably standardly configured.)

Comment: This sounds like a `fontconfig` issue to me. If you don't have the core 35 installed, you may get something which doesn't look right, but you should still get something intelligible. As for the 35, there will be a package you can install with your distro package manager to provide these. (You can also teach `fontconfig` to use the font directories in TeX Live, which is another option.)

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.*

> Your question does not seem LaTeX related -- rather related to a
>   specific LaTeX editor. Maybe it's better to ask on a site that is
>   specific to the editor you refer to.

Fonts are normally embedded in the pdf file -- even commercial fonts (there are exceptions).

There are 14 so-called base fonts that are normally not embedded (I had the problem when using the statistic software GNU R):

```
Courier, Courier Bold, Courier Oblique, Courier Bold-Oblique,
Helvetica, Helvetica Bold, Helvetica Oblique, Helvetica Bold-Oblique,
Times Roman, Times Bold, Times Italic, Times Bold-Italic,
Symbol,
Zapf Dingbats.
```

> Adobe includes the following fonts with Acrobat Reader. You do not
>   have to embed these fonts in PDF files.

- https://appligent.com/what-are-the-base-14-fonts/
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51711_01/TSG/FAQ/What%20are%20the%2014%20base%20fonts%20distributed%20with%20Acroba.html#faqc02_3586048109_36531

Comment: It doesn't sound like an editor problem to me.

Comment: @cfr Yeah, maybe. I don't use Linux or the other software mentioned in the question. I remembered the problem with the base fonts and thought that it's related maybe. That's all :).